# REACT Injecting dynamically SVG. react-svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a dumb component that gets passed down props from a weatherAPI. I want to be able to dynamically change the SVG image depending on what gets sent back from the API. I have installed an npm module `react-svg`: https://github.com/atomic-app/react-svg. This has a dependency of `svg-injector`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-injector which I have also installed. I am currently running all the right versions of `npm`, `react` and `react-dom` that these dependencies depend on. For now, I am just trying to pull in an SVG using the `react-svg` module. Here is the file:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import styles from '../common/contentBoxStyles';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';

const WeatherReport = ({report}) => {
return (
    <div style={styles.body} className="row">
        <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer}>
            <div className="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    <ReactSVG path={'../common/svg/O1n.svg'} callback={(svg) => console.log(svg)} />
                    <div className="row" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.temps}>
                        <div className="col-sm-4">
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.main.temp_max)}°</div>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.main.temp_min)}°</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.currentTemp}>
                            {Math.floor(report.main.temp)}°
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                CA
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    Report
                </div>
                UT
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    Report
                </div>
                MN
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    Report
                </div>
                DC
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    Report
                </div>
                NY
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

WeatherReport.propTypes = {
    report: PropTypes.object
   };

export default WeatherReport;
```

Here is the file tree for reference:

```
src
|_ _components
|   |_ _dashboard
|   |   |_ _WeatherReport.js
|   |_ _common
|       |_ _svg
|           |_ _O1n.svg
```

Am I missing something that needs to be done here? Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can trouble shoot this? I should note that I have attempted to place the SVG inside the `dashboard` folder as to ensure a direct path to see if that would work. Unfortunately, it does not.

My console is currently logging through my callback property: 
`Unable to load SVG file: ../common/svg/O1n.svg`
`undefined`

The `callback` property is working for `react-svg`.. It is the path that cannot be resolved and I am unsure as to why. If you have any other simple suggestions on how else I can approach the goal I am trying to reach outside of `react-svg`, feel free to mention.

Thanks for any time spend answering or helping with this current dilemma that I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ReactSVG`'s `path` needs to be relative to the document root you're serving from NOT relative to the js file that contains `ReactSVG`

Comment: Hey Jack, I appreciate your response. I was wondering if you are referring to the path where I am importing `ReactSVG` or the path of the property of the ReactSVG component.

Comment: The `path` prop used with `ReactSVG`: `<ReactSVG path={...}`

Comment: Hmm. I'm fairly new to using `webpack` & `react`. Maybe I am not understanding where the document root for serving my app is. Everything that is being served is under my `src` folder. So in theory I should be able to refer to my SVG from the `src` folder yes? Instead of `../common/svg/O1n.svg` (which is relative to the js file that contains `ReactSVG`), it should be `./src/components/common/svg/O1n.svg`? Appreciate your help Jack.

Comment: The easiest way would be to get your `.svg` to display in the browser by going to it directly to it like if you're really serving from `src` then it would be something like (guessing port) `http://localhost:3000/components/common/svg/01n.svg` then if you set `<ReactSVG path={'/components/common/svg/01n.svg'} .... />` it should work.

Comment: Alright, what you are saying makes total sense. I'm starting to think this might not be possible as I am using `react-router`.  To my understanding unless defined in my routes folder, I wont be able to access this SVG file. Nor can I import an SVG file.

Comment: Well, something is serving the js so that `react-router` can work. If you're using a boilerplate react project there's probably already a `static` or `assets` folder that is setup to be served outside of the react stuff.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, I am using a boilerplate react project. I might have a thing or two to learn in regards to `webpack`. Right now I am using `react-slingshot`: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot and currently only the `webpack.config.dev.js` file. To me it seems that everything is being served from the `src` file, but I could be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm using this plugin: [react-inlinesvg](https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-inlinesvg)

With this is I can load a local file like this:

```
import SVG from 'react-inlinesvg';

 <SVG src="../../images/logo.svg">
 </SVG>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the svg inline with something like this

```
export const Logo = (props) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 180 27" {...props}>
    <path
      d="M112.2,9.6h-0.6v...z"
    />
  </svg>
);
```

then

```
import { Logo } from "../path/to/file"
```

This is cool because it gives you more options to play with besides just `fill`